# how to draw OpenGL geometry in Qt 5.7 using glew

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to render a triangle in a QGLWidget (Qt5.7) but by some reason, I am unable to show the triangle on screen, only the blue background is showed.

myapp.pro file:

```
QT += core gui opengl

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = myapp
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += ../../libs/glew/include

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    ../../libs/glew/src/glew.c \
    glwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    ../../libs/glew/include/GL/glew.h \
    glwindow.h
```

This is the main function:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <glwindow.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  glwindow v;
  v.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

The window header:

```
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>

class glwindow : public QGLWidget
{
public:
  glwindow();
protected:
  void initializeGL() override;
  void paintGL() override;
};
```

The cpp file:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <glwindow.h>

GLfloat vertices[] = {
  +0.0f, +1.0f,
  -1.0f, -1.0f,
  +1.0f, -1.0f
};

glwindow::glwindow()
{}

void setupGeometry()
{
  GLuint buffer_id;
  glGenBuffers(1, &buffer_id);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer_id);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
}

void glwindow::initializeGL()
{
  glewInit();
  setupGeometry();
}

void glwindow::paintGL()
{
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

Update 1:
Added the shader code:

```
const GLchar *vs = "#version 150 // Specify which version of GLSL we are using."
                 "in  vec2 in_Position;"
                 "void main() "
                 "{"
                 "    gl_Position = vec4(in_Position.x, in_Position.y, 0.5, 1.0);"
                 "}";
const GLchar *fs = "#version 150 // Specify which version of GLSL we are using."
                 "precision highp float; // Video card drivers require this line to function properly"
                 "out vec4 fragColor;"
                 "void main()"
                 "{"
                 "    fragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0); //Set colour of each fragment to WHITE"
                 "}";
```

The function that setup shader is:

```
void checkShader(GLuint ID)
{
  GLint compile_status = 0;
  glGetShaderiv(ID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_status);
  if(compile_status != GL_TRUE)
    {
      GLint info_length;
      GLsizei buffer_size;
      glGetShaderiv(ID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &info_length);
      GLchar *message = new GLchar[info_length];
      glGetShaderInfoLog(ID, info_length, &buffer_size, message);
      delete[] message;
    }
}

void initShader()
{
  GLuint program_id;
  GLuint vs_id, fs_id;

  vs_id = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  fs_id = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

  const char *adapter[1];
  adapter[0] = vs;
  glShaderSource(vs_id, 1, adapter, 0);
  adapter[1] = fs;
  glShaderSource(fs_id, 1, adapter, 0);

  glCompileShader(vs_id);
  checkShader(vs_id);

  glCompileShader(fs_id);
  checkShader(fs_id);

  program_id = glCreateProgram();
  glAttachShader(program_id, vs_id);
  glAttachShader(program_id, fs_id);

  glLinkProgram(program_id);
  glUseProgram(program_id);
}
```

So, the init function is changed to

```
void glview::initializeGL()
{
  glewInit();
  initGeometry();
  initShader();
}
```

The shader initialization is failed with error message :
**(GLchar *) 0x7efe21 \":1(10): error: GLSL 1.50 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, and 3.00 ES\n\"**

Comment: If you're using Qt 5.7, you should avoid QGLWidget which is deprecated: use the [new Qt OpenGL classes](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-index.html#opengl-and-opengl-es-integration). You will find dedicated objects to encapsulate most of your calls. See also [QOpenGLWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwindow.html). You should remove glew from your project since (at best) it is redundant with Qt management for OpenGL functions

Comment: Where are your shaders? You either need to use the fixed pipeline (deprecated), or "modern" OpenGL with shaders. Right now you're using aspects of both. Mainly, you use generic vertex attributes, which can only be used with shaders.

Comment: @wasthishelpful, the reason I am not using Qt OpenGL class is QGLShaderProgram only support GLSL 1.x

Comment: Hum... Your comment doesn't make any sense. You are using Qt OpenGL and QGLShaderProgram does not support only GLSL 1.x. What did you want to explain with your comment?

Comment: The reason I tried to use the old QGLWidget is I tried the example http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html. After that, I tried to use glsl version 430. But I got a runtime error saying glsl 430 is not supported. So I tried to use the old way to combine QGLWidget and glew. That is where I got the current problem. And you are right about my comment, I should write something like "I am not using the recommend Qt OpenGL wrapper".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt 5.7 only supports to glsl 1.3.0. So if ppl want to use glsl 4.3, try glfw or SDL.